# Helping users write regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am working on a project where there are formatting rules for certain text fields.

Users are able to edit these rules. Currently, the rules are regular expressions. The users see regular expressions as very intimidating and would like an easier more user friendly way to write them.

I have in mind some simple translation tool... where users could enter # for a digit... X for a letter, etc.. But I know that the day will come when they need more than letters and digits.

I wonder if a simple translation tool exists or if there is a better way to do this?

Thank you for reading, all suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1991264/944681)

Comment: how do they define them? Do they write them in a text file, or via a web form? If you used a form you could use buttons with things like 'digit' written on them (instead of writing a DSL over the top of a DSL)

Comment: they write them through a form

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly straightforward to create a tool such as you are proposing.  Simply expand your placeholders into corresponding regex values:

```
var input= "XX##*"
var regex = input.replace('#', '[0-9]')
regex = regex.replace('X', '[a-zA-Z]')
regex = regex.replace('*', '.*')
# etc
```

Of course, you will have to define your placeholders and any other options you want to provide your users.  You could also get creative and allow power users to enter a regex directly by surrounding input with `/` (or some other identifier).

```
var input= '/\d\d\w\w.*/'
var regex = undefined;
if (input.matches('^/(.*)/$')) {
    regex = $1  (group 1 from regex)
} else {
  regex = input.replace('#', '[0-9]')
  regex = regex.replace('X', '[a-zA-Z]')
  regex = regex.replace('*', '.*')
}
```

Of course, this is entirely a made up language to demonstration the solution...  If you find a way to compile it, I would be most interested.  :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will update with my finished answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Split string into single characters and apply

   - Replace each `X` with `[a-zA-Z]`
   - Replace each `#` with `\d`
   - Replace each `^` with `\^`
   - All others replace with `[*]`, where `*` is the character you are replacing
2. Join all patterns into one final regex pattern
3. If you want to apply regex pattern to the entire string, add `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the comment I will be using this somehow.